# Open raw text recourse and diplay wrong next line

Tags: android, text

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(idtext);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String myText = "";
int in;
try {
    in = inputStream.read();
    while (in != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(in);
        in = inputStream.read();
    }
    inputStream.close();
    myText = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
myTextView.setText(myText); `
```

My code is used to display long text file in raw res. I don't know why, but some of text file display wrong about next line, any help?

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you can share some sample display vs your expected output.

From the initial guess, it could be because of couple of reasons:

1. The encoding used in the text file. So, if you have written the text in ASCII and displaying it while using UTF-8 strings, it would mess up few things. This should be consistent.
2. Could be a good case of how line feeds are encoding in the file, like `\r\n` or just `\n`.
3. You can also try encapsulating your `InputStream` to `FileReader` and line reading streams which are more specialized in directly reading strings, rather than converting it.
4. You can probably use a library like [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to manage all the stuffs for you.